# How do I find all highlighted text in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have a LibreOffice Writer document that has undergone a process of editing, and sections of the text that needed to be rewritten were highlighted in yellow. As I fixed those sections, I removed the yellow highlight.

Now, I want to make sure there are no remaining areas of highlighted text that have not been fixed or possibly the highlight was not removed.

It's many hundreds of pages, so a manual scan is unfeasible. Also, it might be that one space or one character got accidentally left highlighted, and I want to ensure I've accounted for them all.

How can I search the document to find all instances where text has been highlighted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can search for text with a particular background color:

1. Open Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Find and replace`";
2. In the "`Find & Replace`" dialogue, click on Button <kbd>More Options</kbd>, then click on the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button:

   [image]
3. Now, select the "`Background`" tab and select the appropriate color to search for:

   [image]
4. In the "`Text Format (Search)`" dialogue, click <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Now, back in the "`Find & Replace`" dialogue, just click <kbd>Find</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to select my own custom color?

Comment: @Felipe: i didn't find a quick and easy way to do this. You may achieve this by editing the palette, but this would be worth a separate question.